# The intersection of a countable set of open subsets of a Baire space is a Baire space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be a collection of open topological subspaces of a Baire space. Then each $A_\alpha$ is also a Baire space. Suppose that $\{B_n\}\subset \bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$ were a countable collection of closed subspaces, each with an empty interior. Then, as $\{B_n\} \subset A_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$, so the union $\bigcup_n B_n$ also has empty interior, since $A_\alpha$ is a Baire space. Thus, $\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$ is a Baire space.

I know there's a problem with this proof. The above argument makes no claims about cardinality. That is, if the above proof is assumed correct, then for each $q_\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}^c$, define $A_\alpha=(-\infty, q_\alpha)\bigcup(q_\alpha, \infty)$. Then, $A_\alpha$ is open, and $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$. Then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a Baire space. And this is false. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Baire space. There has to be something wrong with my proof above--I know the statement should be that if $A_\alpha$ is countable, then their intersection is Baire, but I can't figure out where in my proof I go wrong with the uncountability argument.